# C# WPF Fullscreening Frames (Resize) from a Page (of Frame) Button click event

Tags: c#, wpf

**What is this:** I am building a media application to allow the user to view files and open them. For right now, I only have one category, which is movies.

**Intro to the problem (What I am trying to accomplish):** I have a full screen button, that once clicked will make the movie full screen to the frame (Page) and the window of the whole application will also full screen (borderless).

**The problem:** My problem as hinted through the text is to full screen the movie to the whole application, not just frame. I have an idea of how to get the application window, through the following code, but I am unable to find out how to select the frame of the application, and resize its contents to the application when the user clicks the button to fullscreen.

(Its kind of annoying seeing bits of the application around the actual movie/media, and the hamburger menu):

**VideoPlayer page button click event for fullscreen button:**

```
private void Fullscreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wnd = Window.GetWindow(this);
        if (Player.Height == System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight && Player.Width == System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)
        {
            wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            wnd.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            Player.Width = (double)Application.Current.Properties["VideoWidth"];
            Player.Height = (double)Application.Current.Properties["VideoHeight"];

        }
        else if (Player.Height != wnd.Width && Player.Width != System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)
        {
            ;
            wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            wnd.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            Player.Width = wnd.Width;
            Player.Height = wnd.Height;

        }
```

My MainWindow x:Name - "HomeWindow" and class - "MainWindow"

Frame x:Name="Home"

OR if I can't resize the frame or use it, at least access the other elements like the hamburger menu and inside the event, make those elements hidden.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Not to be hardish but you have to come to the point. Don't explain your whole program in a text block of text. 99% of members that read your question, won't even bother reading that. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adapt yours to it. As short as possible but with all necessary details about the issue.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I will edit it. Sorry about the length. I just don't want people to have any shortage of information answering the question.